# Problems creating image thumbnails with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-manipulation

I'm trying to use the image manipulation class to create thumbnails of images. Here's my relevant method:

```
public function create_thumbnail($source_img, $name, $file_ext)
{
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $source_img;
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 50;
    $config['new_image'] = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\\' .  $name . 't' . $file_ext;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();exit;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

When the script is run, I get this error:

```
Unable to save the image. Please make sure the image and file directory are writable.
```

The array element `$config['new_image']` evaluates to something like this: `C:\xampp\htdocs\EuzIDct.jpg`, so I know it's not that. The source file also exists at the time the method is called, so it's not that either.

Does anyone have any clue what's going on here? I Google'd the problem but the solution from the CI forums is saying specify an absolute path nor a relative one, which is what I'm doing but alas it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you on Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: Windows, thought `'C:\xampp\htdocs\\'` gave it away, sorry.

Comment: My bad. Is that file read-only? Right-click on it and check it's properties...

Answer (score 0):

First try removing the extra backslash in your filepath.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\
```

Next, right click and check the file permissions on that directory.

Failing that, run the xampp server as admin as a short term fix to see if it is some other permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are running a permission problem. Just attempt to change your folder permissions.
Although your image_lib->resize() approach isn't incorrect, I hardly recommend you using another way to resize those images. Usually 777 permissions expose your application in terms of security. 
I recommend using FTP to move those thumbnails instead of codeigniter image_lib.
If you still insist using write permissions, right-click on C:\xampp\htdocs\ -> proprieties, tab security, edit, add user everyone and give him full-access(windows). For Linux-Mac, just a simple chmod -R 777.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. In my case, I put the image source and new_image without base_url or REAL_PATH:

```
public function create_thumbnail($file_name='2012_02_23_15_06_00_1.jpg'){
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = 'assets/img/content/article/'.$file_name;
    $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $config['width'] = 210;
    $config['height'] = 160;    
    $config['new_image'] = 'assets/img/content/article/thumb/thumb_' .  $file_name;

    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
    if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
    {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();exit;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

See?
you don't put

```
$config['new_image'] = base_url().'assets/img/content/article/thumb/thumb_' .  $file_name;
```

but

```
$config['new_image'] = 'assets/img/content/article/thumb/thumb_' .  $file_name;
```

using `base_url()`, either your image_source or your new_image will have prefix `http://domain_or_localhost`.

using REAL_PATH like `C://htdocs/blablabla/` just complicates things such as unwritable, etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

your new image path is going to wrong.
it store image in root directory.
$config['new_image'] = '/folder name/new_image.jpg';